# Como eu converto uma imagem RGB para escala de cinza em Python?

Tags: python

Preciso converter diversas imagens (no formato `.png`) coloridas RGB para escala de cinza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito com a biblioteca [pillow](https://python-pillow.github.io/):

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.png').convert('L')
img.save('greyscale.png')
```

<sup>[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201744/520779) (adaptada). [Documentação do método `convert`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert).</sup>

(o código acima pode parecer estranho, mas pillow é um *fork* da biblioteca PIL, já obsoleta)

Não sei se é possível fazer nativamente, sem o uso de bibliotecas externas. A resposta no SOen linkada acima dá um outro exemplo, com [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) e [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) para fazer isso. Para instalá-lo:

```
pip install Pilow
```

No seu código, a única coisa que você precisa fazer é converter o modo da imagem.

```
from PIL import Image

# abre a imagem colorida
img_colorida = Image.open('imagem_colorida.png')

# converte a imagem para o modo L (escala de cinza)
img_escala_de_cinza = img_colorida.convert('L')

# salva a nova imagem
img_escala_de_cinza.save('imagem_escala_de_cinza.png')
```

Caso suas imagens originais tenham transparência, utilize o modo `LA` em vez de somente `L`.